# xmllint does not work properly with xpath

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, xml-parsing, xmllint

Here is what I have. It clearly doesn't do what it supposed to and it even crashed. Is something wrong or is there any other tool that can help me parse XML in BASH?

```
:~$ cat test.xml 
<project xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/project/1">
  <type>org.netbeans.modules.ant.freeform</type>
</project>

:~$ xmllint --xpath '//type/text()' test.xml 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

:~$ xmllint --xpath '//type' test.xml 
XPath set is empty
```

Comment: Which version of libxml2 are you using (`xmllint --version`)?

Answer (score 1):

To search for a namespaced element, you can test the local name, like this:

```
xmllint --xpath '//*[local-name()="type"]/text()' test.xml
```

A more precise way would be

```
xmllint --xpath '//*[namespace-uri()="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/project/1" and local-name()="type"]/text()' test.xml
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that your XML... Is not a valid XML file.

Try this before :

```
sed -i '1i <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' test.xml
```

And after testing, you have a *namespace* problem so try this :

```
xmllint --shell test.xml
/ > setns x=http://www.netbeans.org/ns/project/1
/ > xpath /x://type/text()
```

Comment: I had that in there and it didn't work either so I removed it just to check that xmllint does not have a problem with that... And it's still  a valid XML file, even without it (other tools don't mind if the first line is missing)

Comment: The problem is your namespace, not the XML first line

Comment: how can this be a problem? as I see it, I would blame the tool, not the XML structure

Comment: it works without the namespace but I just can't remove it randomly :)

Comment: `xpath /x://type/text()` gives me `XPath error : Invalid expression` pointing at the `:/` part

Comment: also in the real world I have many different namespaces in the document so it would be great if I could just make the tool work without specifiyng them...

Comment: Have you tried without `:` ?

Comment: yes, no change... but i want those namespaces to remain there and without need to specify them explicitely... also --shell option does not work for me since I have to use xmllint in a script